# Make graph twice as big as on screen with knitr

Tags: r, ggplot2, knitr

Using the following `ggplot2` code I can make plot twice as big as on screen.

```
ratings <- qplot(rating, data=movies, geom="histogram")
ggsave(ratings, file="ratings.pdf", scale=2)
```

I wonder how to display plot twice as big as on screen with `knitr`.

```
<< label = test, fig.width  = 6, fig.height = 6, out.width  = '.6\\linewidth'>>=
ratings <- qplot(rating, data=movies, geom="histogram")
@
```

but did not get plot twice as big as on screen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By writing out.width  = '.6\linewidth' you force the scaling back. Have you tried to leave this one out?